# Regex to extract data between 3 - 8 digit number and 3 letter text(casplock text)

Tags: c#, .net, regex, rpa, uipath

I wanted to extract the data between 3 - 8 digit number and 3 letter text(casplock text) using regex. Any idea would be much appreciated thank you.

Data (which is a string)

"06/29/20       B      QM      02004946        TEST HOME MORTGAGE                                               TRU

03/10/20       B      BC      2440720         BK OF TEST                                                        XPN

03/07/20       B      QZ      00060298        CPORT RU                                                          TRU"

OUTPUT should be :  TEST HOME MORTGAGE ,   BK OF TEST  and  CPORT RU

Comment: Is this a typo `0829/20` ? should it be `08/29/20` ?

Comment: yeah just a typo

Comment: Give this a try: `\d{3,8}\s+(?<capture>.*)\s+[A-Z]{3}$`. The `?<capture>` is optional and can be used for naming the match that you want to have.

Comment: I did try that but it did not get the right data

Comment: Accoring to this, all your examples will work as expected: https://regex101.com/r/kuE6dS/1

Comment: for example in this input 06/29/20 B QM 12345678 MY HELLO WORLD XLS

it should only get MY HELLO WORLD and highlight , it should not highlight XLS and the numbers

Comment: It is working for me the solution that Sebastian provided. Check match information Section (Just right side) as Group Capture  with \d{3,8}\s+(?<capture>.*)\s+[A-Z]{3}$ on "regex101.com/r/kuE6dS/1".

Comment: This question has completely changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this

- Zero-width positive lookbehind
- Zero-width positive lookahead

**Update**

```
var pattern = @"(?<=\d{3,8}\s).*(?=\s[A-Z]{3})";

var input = @"06/29/20 B QM 02004946 MY HELLO WORLD XLS
08/29/20 B QM 0948264 MY UI PATH LMN
08/29/20 B QM 435 MY SAMPLE DATA LMN
06/29/20 B QM 123 MY HELLO WORLD XLS";

var results = Regex
       .Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)
       .Cast<Match>()
       .Select(x => x.Value);

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", results));
```

**Output**

```
MY HELLO WORLD, MY UI PATH, MY SAMPLE DATA, MY HELLO WORLD
```

[**Full Demo Here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uvqfpJ)

---

**Original**

Pattern

```
(?<=\d{3,8}\s).*(?=\s[A-Z]{3}$)
```

**Usage**

```
var pattern = @"(?<=\d{3,8}\s).*(?=\s[A-Z]{3}$)";

var strings = new List<string>()
{
   "06/29/20 B QM 02004946 MY HELLO WORLD XLS",
   "08/29/20 B QM 0948264 MY UI PATH  LMN",
   "08/29/20 B QM 435 MY SAMPLE DATA   LMN"
};

var results = strings.Select(x => Regex.Match(x, pattern).Value);

foreach (var result in results)
   Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
MY HELLO WORLD
MY UI PATH
MY SAMPLE DATA
```

[**Full Demo here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1NUhwE)

Comment: IVE TRIED IT ON UIPATH , WORKS FINE.

Comment: IT DID NOT WORK WHEN SAMPLE INPUT IS "06/29/20 B QM 123 MY HELLO WORLD XLS"

Comment: I tried on https://regex101.com/. It is giving pattern Error.

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin works for me https://dotnetfiddle.net/1NUhwE

Comment: it should be between 3 to 8 digits and 3 Letters . so it should consider

Comment: @Mr.MarkTawin can you give me a breaking example. I am not sure i fully understand the requirements

Comment: @VikasGarg the regex is valid

Comment: @MichaelRandall sir what if its a single string ? I have updated my question , can you please check it . thanks